# Insert Into Select From a Table and Strings and Nulls in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table:

table_a

```
id, start_date, tracking_date, type, relationship_id
```

Essentially, I'm trying to remove the tracking_date column and to preserve the data, create a new record for each record with a non-null tracking date. The new record should be a copy of the original record, except the start_date should be the value of the original row's tracking_date, the new tracking_date should be NULL and lastly the type should be the string value "type_b" for all records modified in this way.

My query so far is:

```
INSERT INTO table_a
  (id, start_date, tracking_date, type, relationship_id)
SELECT (id, start_date, NULL, "type_b", relationship_id)
FROM table_a
WHERE tracking_date IS NOT NULL;
```

I don't think selecting NULL and/or the string value "type_b" from table_a is valid. I was wondering how I might use the INSERT INTO SELECT FROM query structure to insert values from another table as well as NULL and string values in the same query. (or in multiple queries)

BEFORE

```
table_a
id, start_date, tracking_date, type, relationship_id
1, 1/1/1999, NULL, type_a, 100
1, 1/2/1999, 1/3/1999, type_a, 100
```

AFTER

```
table_a
id, start_date, tracking_date, type, relationship_id
1, 1/1/1999, NULL, type_a, 100
1, 1/2/1999, 1/3/1999, type_a, 100
1, 1/3/1999, NULL, type_b, 100
```

(The idea is that afterwards, I would delete the tracking_date column))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the parentheses around the column list in the `select`.

`(id, start_date, NULL, "type_b", relationship_id)` is a **single** column with an anonymous record type.

See the manual for details: [Row Constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

---

Additionally: strings have to be put between **single** quotes. Double quotes (`"`) are for identifiers. `"type_b"` is the name of a column, `'type_b'` is a character string.

See the manual for details: [Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

---

So the query should be:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (id, start_date, tracking_date, type, relationship_id)
SELECT id, start_date, NULL, 'type_b', relationship_id
FROM table_a
WHERE tracking_date IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That did the trick, removing the parenthesis and switching to using single quotes for the static value fixed it. (I also had to remove the id field from both parts of the query since it was the primary key.) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your tracking_date field is defined as a timestamp. In that case try the following. If that doesn't work, what is the error you are getting?

```
INSERT INTO table_a 
(id, start_date, tracking_date, type, relationship_id) 
SELECT 
(id, start_date, NULL::timestamp, "type_b", relationship_id) 
FROM table_a 
WHERE tracking_date IS NOT NULL;
```